# How to code in selenium c# when a html attribute changes value to show a field is valid?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a method below where I enter in a postcode, select the find address button and I expect some fields to be visible:

```
    public void CompletePostcodeLookup()
    {
        _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.PostcodeLookupField).SendKeys("LS11 9AW");
        _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.FindAddressBtn).Click();


        _driver.WaitToBeInvisible(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.FindAddressBtn, 5);
        _driver.WaitToBeVisible(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.AddressManualHouseNumberField, 5);
        _driver.WaitToBeVisible(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.AddressLineOneField, 5);
        _driver.WaitToBeVisible(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.AddressCityField, 5);
        _driver.WaitToBeVisible(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.AddressManualPostcodeField, 5);
        _driver.WaitToBeVisible(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.AddressCounty, 5);

    }
```

Now not only am I expecting the fields to be visible, but these fields should be valld and in the HTML we can determine these fields are valid based on this...

```
<input... aria-invalid='false'>
```

So what i did in my PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.cs page is included a method that finds any input that contains this:

```
 public static By ValidFields => By.XPath("//input[@aria-invalid='false']");
```

Now this may be the icorrect way of doing things but I wanted to know that if I wanted to check that all of these visiable fields are valid, what is the correct way to code it? Should i even place them in an 'Assert'?

Edit:

I included all methods into one method, if I can do an assertion based on none of these methods have an invalid field then should be ok:

```
public void CompleteContactDetailsForm()
{
    SelectBookingContact();
    CompletePostcodeLookup();
    CompletePhoneNumberFields();
    CompleteEmailAddressFields();

}
```

Thanks

Comment: When you do a unit test it is ok to assert, because the nature of the test is to fail if anything is wrong. But when do test automation, our job is not only to find or stop at the first failure but get a bigger picture. So assuming that you have a field who's validation is failing but rest of the test can continue and test further. Then it should go ahead and proceed further. The test can fail on cosmetic issues and continue still, but if it is a critical issue then test should fail with assert, So I would check each filed, store the result and assert on the combination with complete details

Comment: @TarunLalwani That makes sense, I updated question should the all methods combined within one method, is it possible to then do an assert of the valid fields in combination as you stated with these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st way: 
You may consider writing a for loop to check that each webElement has value: invalid='false'  (you may do this by writing simple parser)

2nd  way: 
You can do it by reading complete list of desired Web elements in an Array List and iterate through it using iterator like [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform)

Regarding Assert, that should be placed on final step (.cs file where you are calling this case).